# 2021年12月時点のGoogle ColabのPythonバージョンを知りたい

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

2021年12月時点でのGoogle colabのPythonバージョンについてなのですがどなたか解る方ございませんでしょうか。
現在のバージョンはPython 3.7.12で当時も同じだった記憶があるのですが確証を持てず記載する必要がある情報でしたので確認を取りたいと考えています。

Comment: 「確証/確認」が必要ならGoogleに問い合わせるしかないのでは？

Comment: 確証まではいらない状態で、一応バージョンを載せておく程度の物になります。

Answer (score 1):

閲覧、コメントしてくださった方々などご協力ありがとうございました。
今回、自己解決することができました。

12月当時のgoogle-colaboratoryのPythonバージョンについてなのですが、3.7.12である可能性が非常に高いことがわかりました。

昨年の8/22時点ではPythonバージョンは3.7.11でしたが、現在では3.7.12となっているうえ参照したブログなどの情報でも多くの物が10月、11月の時点で3.7.12としていることから3.7.12であろうと思われます。

画像での表記になりますが、現在のgoogle-colaboratoryのPythonバージョンになります。

[image: 現在のgoogle-colaboratory_Pythonバージョン]

そして以下が参考にしたブログなどになります。
4つのブログ記事や現在のPythonバージョンから12月時点も3.7.12であったという結論に至りました。
各ブログ事に書いている人物などが異なると考えられることから12月の情報については比較的信頼のとれる情報にはなると思います。

[参考1(昨年8月時点)](https://lsp.hatenablog.jp/entry/2021/02/24/213503)
[参考2(昨年11月時点)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11253044076)
[参考3(昨年10月時点)](https://teratail.com/questions/365437)
[参考4(昨年11月時点)](https://python.iitter.com/other/254559.html)